# In Chrome Dev Tools, after clicking on the magnifying glass in the Computed tab, how do you remove that selection from the Styles tab? (more inside)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Alright, so in Chrome's Dev Tools (F12) I clicked on the Computed tab for an element and then on the magnifying glass icon next to one of the styles (margin-bottom).  After clicking on this magnifying glass, under the Styles table "margin-bottom" is now highlighted in yellow at the top.

How do I remove this watch in the Styles tab?  I don't want the yellow  "margin-bottom" to be there anymore.